# How do I change the page numbering position for a specific page in latex?

Tags: header-footer, landscape

I am using landscape for a particular page in latex, because I want to fit a large table. So, I rotate the landscape for the table to be easily readable. However, now the page number appears on the left because of the rotation. I want to change the position of this particular page to the right, so that because of the rotation, the page number appears to be at the bottom. Please suggest how to do so. Thanks.

Comment: How are you rotating the page? Using [`geometry`](http://ctan.org/pkg/geometry)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Package `rotating` with environment `sidewaystable` only rotates the table, but let the header and footer unchanged and unrotated:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a6paper]{geometry}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage{rotating}

\begin{document}
\begin{sidewaystable}
  \begin{tabular}{p{95mm}}
  \toprule
  \lipsum*[1]\tabularnewline
  \bottomrule
  \end{tabular}
\end{sidewaystable}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]